# Google App Script - Summarizes Result from Multiple Rows and Columns with Same Area Name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a data containing test results of multiple tests performed at different locations in a general area. I am struggling to write a script that summarizes the results in the following way in a separate tab using Google AppScript:

Test 1 to 3 are mandatory and if they:

- all Pass, summary should record Pass
- any Fail, summary should record Fail
- any Partial Pass, summary should record Partial Pass
- any Missing, summary should record Result Missing

Test 4 is optional and can be ignored

**Input:**

[image: Input]

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Comment: Are you set on creating a script for this, or would you be interested in using a formula, given there was one that worked?

Comment: Need a script because actual data is too big and gets updated daily

Comment: Your data doesn't match your request.  D Test_4 fails so D should fail.  A Test_4 data missing so should be Result Missing

Comment: @TheWizEd `Test 4 is optional and can be ignored`

Comment: Yes but Area D fails

Comment: @TheWizEd Yes, but that information is irrelevant since Test_4 is optional and should be ignored. It does not play a factor into the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Description**

The following example script will first determine the unique areas.  Then for each area examine the test results by row and determine if any fail.  Test_4 results are ignored.  And Fail takes precedence over Partial Pass.

I've included the execution log with console.log steps along the way to show how the data is reduced.

**Code.gs**

```
function test () {
  try {
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    values.shift(); // remove the headers
    values.forEach( row => row.pop() ); // remove Test_4 results
    console.log(values);

    // get unique areas
    let areas = values.map( row => row[0] );
    console.log(areas);
    areas = [...new Set(areas)]
    console.log(areas);

    // find results for each area
    let results = areas.map( area => [area,"Pass"]);
    console.log(results);

    values.forEach( row => {  let index = areas.findIndex( area => area === row[0] );
                              let tests = row.slice(2);
                              if( tests.indexOf("Fail") >= 0 ) {
                                results[index][1] = "Fail";
                                return;
                              }
                              else if( tests.indexOf( "Partial Pass") >= 0 ) {
                                results[index][1] = "Partial Pass";
                                return;
                              }
                              else if( tests.indexOf( "" ) >= 0 ) {
                                results[index][1] = "Results Missing";
                                return;
                              }
                            }
                  );
    console.log(results);

  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
3:25:42 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:25:43 PM  Info    [ [ 'A', 1, 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass' ],
  [ 'A', 2, 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass' ],
  [ 'A', 3, 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass' ],
  [ 'B', 1, 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass' ],
  [ 'B', 2, 'Fail', 'Pass', 'Pass' ],
  [ 'C', 1, 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass' ],
  [ 'C', 2, 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Fail' ],
  [ 'C', 3, 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass' ],
  [ 'D', 1, 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass' ],
  [ 'D', 2, 'Pass', 'Partial Pass', 'Pass' ],
  [ 'D', 3, 'Pass', 'Pass', 'Pass' ],
  [ 'E', 2, '', 'Pass', 'Pass' ] ]
3:25:43 PM  Info    [ 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'E' ]
3:25:43 PM  Info    [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' ]
3:25:43 PM  Info    [ [ 'A', 'Pass' ],
  [ 'B', 'Pass' ],
  [ 'C', 'Pass' ],
  [ 'D', 'Pass' ],
  [ 'E', 'Pass' ] ]
3:25:43 PM  Info    [ [ 'A', 'Pass' ],
  [ 'B', 'Fail' ],
  [ 'C', 'Fail' ],
  [ 'D', 'Partial Pass' ],
  [ 'E', 'Results Missing' ] ]
3:25:44 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [Sheet.getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange())
- [Array.shift()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp)
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Array.pop()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp)
- [Array.map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [Set Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [Array.findIndex()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp)
- [Array.slice()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)
- [Array.indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

Answer (score 0):

- Using a custom function,

  ```
  =RESULTFIXING(A2:A10,C2:E10)
  ```

  Where  Col A contains the area and columns C to E contains the data
- Create a function to  check for empty string or `Partial Pass` or `Fail`. If present, use it, else return `Pass`
- Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)  to create a unique array based on the previous function

#### Sample script with live test:

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
const resultFixing = (area, data) => {
  const compressor = (arr) => {
    const out = arr.find((s) =>
      ['', 'Fail', 'Partial Pass'].some((crit) => s === crit)
    );
    if (out === '') return 'Result Missing';
    return out || 'Pass';
  };
  return [
    ...data
      .reduce(
        (map, arr, i) =>
          map.set(
            area[i][0],
            map.has(area[i][0]) && map.get(area[i][0]) !== 'Pass'
              ? map.get(area[i][0])
              : compressor(arr)
          ),
        new Map()
      )
      .entries(),
  ];
};

console.table(
  resultFixing(
    [/*A2:A7*/['a'], ['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['c'], ['d']],
    [/*C2:D7*/
      ['Pass', 'Pass'],
      ['Pass', 'Fail'],
      ['Partial Pass', 'Pass'],
      ['Pass', 'Pass'],
      ['Pass', ''],
      ['Pass', 'Pass'],
    ]
  )
);
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```